# Keeping activity

Tags: android, android-activity

How to keep the button activity on background/pause or something like  this  when i press the physical back button . I want this activity to set on  when i press again the button.(to show me what did i paint in last activity);

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonSave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDraw);
    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ButtonDraw.class));              
        }
    });    
}
```

ButtonDraw :

```
public class ButtonDraw extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(com.example.myfirstapp.R.layout.paintingfile);

      BlackPixel blackPixel;
      blackPixel = new BlackPixel(this);
      setContentView(blackPixel);
      blackPixel.requestFocus();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking for?  You can override `onBackPressed()` of an activity, but it's difficult to understand what you want to happen.

Comment: Maybe you need to save you state? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MainActivity` include this method:-

```
@Override   


public void onBackPressed() {
  startActivity(new Intent(this,ButtonDraw.class));
  finish(); // this line depends on you whether you want to finish the MainActivity or not.
  }
```

The above method gives you control over the back button of android.